# Android: Store data from MySQL Database in an ArrayList

Tags: android, mysql, arraylist

How can I retrieve data from MySQL database and store it in an `ArrayList`? 
I have already used php scripts to connect to database and get all the data that I want. The data is sent to the webserver in Json format.
Let's say:
1) I have a table in my database based called **users**.
2) I have a class in Android Studio also called **users** that provides all the necessary fields for users. (such as id, name, surname, etc.)
3) I want to create an `ArrayList` (usersList< users>) that contains all the users from the database.
How can I do that?

Comment: You can retrieve MySQL data to Android array list via a web service by adding the proxy to android references.

Comment: Quite long way ahead

Comment: So you have a JSON file with the data?

Comment: I actualy have a php file that gets data from the database and sends it at webserver in JSON format

Answer (score 1):

Use json parsing to convert data from json to array list.

According to your requirement list will contain the different user object after parsing.

[json parsing sample code](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm)